# Don't paginate the results

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

The following is the query I am using to get the results from the database. As you can see it has a chain paginate. I don't want my results to be paginated.

```
return DB::table('example')->where('status', '1')->orderBy('name', 'desc')->paginate(50);
```

When I remove the method `paginate`.

```
return DB::table('example')->where('status', '1')->orderBy('name', 'desc');
```

I get the following error message.

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder could not be
>   converted to string

How can I do that?

Comment: just replace `paginate(50)` with`get()`

Comment: @jfadich awesome thanks. It works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paginate is one of several methods that execute the query. When you remove it you still have an unexecuted query builder. To execute the query without paginating simply use `get()`

```
return DB::table('example')->where('status', '1')->orderBy('name', 'desc')->get();
```